# Visual C++ 2005: How to view the window during a debugging session

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2005, window

Is this possible? When I'm debugging a program I can't bring the window up to see any changes. It's minimized during the debugging while I step through the program and I'd like to see the program changes while I step.

The only way I might see it is in Windows 7 you can hover over the task-bar to get a look at the program but the preview image gets in the way and It's just a weird way to see my program.

I've been trying to search for this problem but all I get is irrelevant results. Maybe I'm missing a few keywords or something. I don't know what to call my problem.

Comment: Your window shouldn't be "permanently minimized" just from attaching the debugger.  What other actions are you taking, and where are your breakpoints set?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that this is while I'm using breakpoints. I'd like to see my window while stepping through the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices:

1. Don't maximize the IDE window and make it smaller until you can see the program window.
2. Have two monitors and put the program window on the secondary monitor.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I ever would of realized that it was behind the IDE the whole time... Why is there no option to keep in the foreground?

Comment: @Mathmagician: I have no idea. I'll agree that it is very annoying though.